# synstack is always empty

Tags: neovim, plugin-treesitter, plugin-synstack

Whenever I do `:echo synstack(line("."), col("."))` it prints `[]`

I've tried this in html and svelte files in my neovim with treesitter, in neovim with `-u NONE`, and in Vim 9 with `-u NONE`. All of them just returning `[]` all the time.

How am I meant to be able to check `synstack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Treesitter is not working with syntax and hence [synstack](https://github.com/dylnmc/synstack.vim) is helpless.

To analyse the syntax result of Treesitter you can use [tresitter-playground](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/playground).

Comment: Yes, and my non-treesitter attempts weren't working because I didn't `:syntax on`